# Using a Date Range with an Input Box and Selecting Data to Copy and Paste

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to perform the following sequence of actions:

1. Open an input box where a start date would be entered, and put that date in a specified cell on a specified sheet.
2. Open an input box where an end date would be entered, and put that date in a specified cell on a specified sheet.
3. Select rows of data from a large dataset that falls between and/or on these dates.
4. Copy that data to another sheet (`sheet2`).

Sample data:

```
Sol Id  Acct No Name    DATE
20  12  JOHN STEVE  16/09/2009
20  13  ROBERT V    31/07/2011
4   14  JOHNNY WALKER   30/04/2012
20  15  LA PRUDENCEE    30/04/2013
20  16  ddd 30/06/2013
11  17  DD  16/09/2013
20  18  EED 30/09/2013
5   19  EED 01/10/2013
20  20  DD  30/11/2013
2   21  RRR 19/12/2013
7   22  RDS 01/01/2014
20  23  DSS 24/01/2014
5   24  223 31/01/2014
5   25  44  31/01/2014
20  26  555 31/01/2014
20  27  666 24/02/2014
```

The dates continue till 31/12/2016. I want to select the start date 16/09/2009, end date 31/12/2015, and paste in `sheet2`.

My VBA code is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Data_Date_Filter()

Dim sDate As Variant, eDate As Variant

sDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting date as mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=1 + 2)
eDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the Ending date as mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=1 + 2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

With Sheet1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("D1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & sDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & eDate
    .Range("D1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It does not copy to sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do what I believe you're trying to do.  Basically you were missing the code to actually paste the values into Sheet2 from Sheet1.

I did the following:

- Added error checking to the date variables since clicking "Cancel" from the input box returned a False value; this caused the autofilter to error.
- Created `wkb` and `wks` variables to make the workbook and worksheet methos easier to follow.
- Added `wkb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial` to handler pasting the copied values into sheet 2.
- Reformatted method properities to follow VBA standards and not the skrewy Excel (":=") syntax.

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub Data_Date_Filter()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim wkb         As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sDate       As Variant
    Dim eDate       As Variant

    Set wkb = Application.ThisWorkbook

    sDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting date as mm/dd/yyyy", , , , , , , vbOKCancel)

    eDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the Ending date as mm/dd/yyyy", , , , , , , vbOKCancel)

    'CHECK IF DATES ARE NULL DUE TO CANCEL BUTTON CLICK
    If sDate = False Or eDate = False Then Exit Sub

    'TURN OFF SCREEN UPDATING AND COPY/PASTE VALUES FROM SHEET1 TO SHEET2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    wkb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents

    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1"): wks.Activate

    With wks
       .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter
       .Range("D1").AutoFilter 4, ">=" & sDate, xlAnd, "<=" & eDate
       .Range("D1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

    wkb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set wks = Nothing: Set wkb = Nothing

    ExitHandler:
       Exit Sub

    ErrHandler:
       Stop: Debug.Print Err.Description: Err.Clear: Resume
  End Sub
  ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for  the vba but it's not working  am getting this      Sol Id Acct No  Name   DATE
5 19 EED    1/10/13
7 22 RDS   1/1/14                                        
suppose to  get  all entries from 16/09/2009 to 31/12/2015 .thanks rakesh